# exisitance of inf

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[0, \infty] \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be a strictly increasing (therefore one-to-one) but not onto function, with $f(0)=0$. For some $c >0$, I want to prove that $\inf\{ x \mid f(x) \ge c\}$ always exists. How do I prove this? We know that 0 is not in the set $\{ x \mid f(x) \ge c\}$ but how can we show that 0 is lower bound of the set? Thanks very much!

Comment: Because the domain is [0,infty).  0 is a lower bound of *EVERY* subset of [0, infty).  There is *nothing* less than zero.

Comment: What if $f(x) = 1- \frac 1{x+1}$ and $c = 2$ then $\inf \{1 - \frac 1{x+1}| 0 \le x \}$ does not exist even though $f(x) $ is strictly increasing.

Comment: "We know that 0 is not in the set "  We know no such thing at all!  consider $f(x) = x + 256$ and $c = 59$.  Then $0 \in \{x|f(x) \ge c\}$ as $f(0) > c$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c = f(1).$ Then it's easy to see that $c > 0, \;$ since $\; 0 \leq f(0) < f(1).$

Since $\{x : \; f(x) \geq c\} \; \neq \; \emptyset \;$ (the number $1$ belongs to this set), it follows that $\{x : \; f(x) \geq c\} \;$ is a nonempty set that is bounded below (by $0),$ and hence by the least upper bound property of the real numbers we have that $\;\inf \{x : \; f(x) \geq c\}$ exists.

Comment: + 1 for noting the OP said for *some* c rather than for *all* c.  Which I completely missed.  And for therefore noting this is an exceedingly simple question with a very clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If $\{ x \mid f(x) \ge c\} \neq \emptyset$ then its infimum exists, since it is a bounded-below subset of $R$.

Note that $x=0$ is a lower bound for the set.

Comment: Actually "how can we show that 0 is lower bound of the set" was the specific question.

Comment: the set is $f^{-1} [c, +\infty )$ which is a subset of domain. The important thing here is non-emptiness of the set,( which might be empty) NOT having zero as it its lower bound (since it is clear as a day )!

Comment: "clear as day" to you and to me, but not to the OP who did specifically ask about it.  Also, we should probably point out that inf f^-1 [c, infinity) might very well *not* exist and the set *could* be empty.  The OP seems to mistakenly assume it can not be and the inf must exist.

Answer (score 0):

<s>As you note, $0$ is not in the set $\{x | f(x) \geq c\}$. This means that $0$ as a lower bound (not necessarily the *greatest* lower bound, but that's not a problem.</s>

An important property of the real numbers is the "completeness" property. This means that if a set is bounded below (or above), then there exists an inf (or sup) for the set. Since your set is bounded below, an inf will always exist.

Edit: To show that $0$ is not in the set, we note that $f$ strictly increasing implies that $f(x) > 0$ for any $x > 0$. But because the domain of $f$ is $[0,\infty)$, $f(0) \geq 0$. This means that $f(c) > 0$ for any $c>0$.

Comment: But $0$ *can* be in the set $\{x\mid f(x)\ge c\}$: For example, $f(x)=x+2$, and $c=1$.

Comment: And the set can be empty.  exampl f(x) = 1 - 1/(x+1); c = 2.

Comment: Your use of c if f(c) > 0 being the same variable as the c in the set f(x) > c, is confusing.  Also we can't claim 0 is not in set if f(0) \ge c which, depending on the choice of c it very well could be.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of the set is $[0, \infty)$ Thus $0 \le x$ for all $x \in [0,\infty)$.  There is nothing lower.  So $0$ is a lower bound of *all* subsets of $[0, \infty)$ and *every* subset of $[0, \infty)$ is bounded below.

Showing that $K \subset [0, \infty)$ is bounded below, is simply not an issue.  The *only* thing we have to show prove $\inf K$ existis is that $K$ is non-empty.  That is *all*.

To show that the must exist *some* $c > 0$ so that $\inf  \{x| f(x) \ge c\}$ we must simply prove there is *some* $c > 0$ so that $ \{x| f(x) \ge c\}$ is not empty.  Simply pick any $c= f(a) > 0$. As $f$ is strictly increasing then for $a > 0$ we know $f(a) > f(0) \ge 0$.  And for all $b \ge a; f(b) \ge f(a) = c$.  So $\{x|f(x) \ge c\} = [a, \infty)$ and $\inf  \{x| f(x) \ge c\} = a$.

======= oops; you wrote for *some* $c$; not for *all* $c$.  Nevermind the rest of this post =====

Which... I don't think we can.  Let $f(x)$ be assymptotic to $d < c$ and $\{x| f(x) \ge c\}$ is empty and $\inf \{x| f(x) \ge c\}$ does not exist.[$*$]

....

Also you claim that $0 \not \in \{x| f(x) \ge c\}$.  There is no reason to assume that at all.  It is perfectly possible for $f(0) \ge c$.[$**$]

[$*$] Example $f(x) = 1 - \frac 1{x+1}; c= 2$ then $ \{x| f(x) \ge c\}= \{x| \frac 1{x+1} \ge 2; x \ge 0\} = \{x| 1 \ge 2x + 2; x\ge 0\}=\{x| x \le -\frac 12 and x \ge 0\}= \emptyset$.

[$**$] Example $f(x) = 256 + x; c = 59$ then $f(x) = 256 > 59$ so $0 \in \{x| f(x) \ge c\}=\{x| 256 + x \ge 59; x \ge 0\} = \{x|x \ge - 197 and x \ge 0\} = \{x| x \ge 0\} = [0 , \infty)$.